# How do I join a table to itself in AREL to find duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activeadmin, arel

I have a table, `transactions`, that may contain duplicates (for us, a duplicate is a `Transaction` with the same `account_id`, `date`, and `amount`).

My English-language functional requirement is "I want to see all transactions for which there exist more than 1 transaction with the same account_id, date, and amount".

Giving up on AREL temporarily, I produced something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions t1, transactions t2
    WHERE t1.id != t2.id 
      AND t1.date = t2.date
      AND t1.amount = t2.amount
      AND t1.account_id = t2.account_id
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.x and Postgres.

Originally, I tried this in AREL:

`Transaction.group(:account_id, :date, :amount).having("count(id) > 1")`

But that gave me the SQL error about aggregate functions:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "transactions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

.. which is frustrating, because I do *not* want the ID in the group by clause -- the whole point is that I want the IDs to be ignored in checking for dupes.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction of the AREL I need to make this a scope -- `find_by_sql` is great when you need records, but I am trying to create an ActiveAdmin scope -- it doesn't like arrays.

Comment: I don't mind the downvotes, but I do mind downvotes with no comments as to why I was downvoted?

Comment: Probably that profile photo :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a scope using sql in your ActiveRecord Transaction model like so:

```
scope :duplicate_transactions, where(<<-eosql.strip)
  transactions.id IN (
      SELECT 
          t1.id 
      FROM 
          transactions t1, transactions t2
      WHERE 
          t1.id != t2.id AND
          t1.date = t2.date AND
          t1.amount = t2.amount AND
          t1.account_id = t2.account_id
  )
eosql
```

But then the id's are involved.. Probably not what you want as this is an expensive query. At least create a non unique index on

```
date, amount, account_id
```

for this table. That should save you some *full table row scanning*... Another way to go about it is to do something like

```
Transaction.joins(<<eosql.strip)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t ON 
      transactions.id         != t.id AND
      transactions.date        = t.date AND
      transactions.amount      = t.amount
eosql
```

Both ways are expensive, memory-wise. Good luck.

Comment: In the end, dipping down into SQL was the easiest -- this is for administration, not for regular use, so I'm fine with a slightly slower query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
def similar
  table = self.class.arel_table
  conditions = %w[ date amount ].map { |field| table[field].eq send(field) }.map &:to_sql
  self.class.where "id != #{ id } AND #{ conditions.join ' AND ' }"
end
```

Comment: this could probably be cleaned up, but it returns an ActiveRecord::Relation

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to have your results returned to you in multiple rows, you could try something like this:

```
select account_id, amount, day, group_concat(id) 
  from purchases 
 group by account_id, amount, day having count(id) > 1;
```

This will return a result set where each row contains the duplicates for a given account, day and amount.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86e43/17

Comment: Upvote for putting me onto this website, but unfortunately, the query you've provided works on MySQL, not Postgres.  I'm on Heroku, so..

Comment: @makdad not super familiar with Postgres but, if your Heroku Postgres is 9.0 or higher, you can use [`string_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html).